# SubmitForm checked value not posting to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of check boxes on `mypage.html.erb`. When I check a box and click the "submit" button, I want the value of what's checked to print on the next page (`bookfinal.html.erb`). For some reason, the checked value doesn't print? In the console, the checked value appears as '1', so I'm not sure what's missing. As you'll see, I added `@checked = "Test"` to see if the value would print, and it still doesn't?

**mypage.html.erb**

```
 <div class="infoheaders">1. Question
   <%= simple_form_for @category, :url => url_for(:action => 'bookfinal', :controller => 'users'), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
     <%= f.collection_select(:title, Category.all, :title, :title) %>
     <div class="grey-text-subheader">Device: (optional)</div>
     <%= f.check_box :Apple %> <%= f.label "Apple" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
     <%= f.check_box :iPhone %> <%= f.label "iPhone" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
     <%= f.check_box :iPad %> <%= f.label "iPad" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
     <%= f.check_box :Mac %> <%= f.label "Mac" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
     <%= f.check_box :Android %> <%= f.label "Android" %><br><br>
     <%= f.check_box :Samsung %> <%= f.label "Samsung" %> &nbsp; &nbsp;  
     <%= f.check_box :Microsoft %> <%= f.label "Microsoft" %>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
     <%= f.check_box :Windows %> <%= f.label "Windows" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
     <%= f.check_box :Google %> <%= f.label "Google" %> 
     <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def bookfinal 
  if params[:category][:ipad].present? 
    @checked = params[:category][:ipad] 
  end 

  if params[:category][:android].present? 
    @checked = params[:category][:android] 
  end 
  if params[:category][:samsung].present? 
    @checked = params[:category][:samsung] 
  end 
  @checked = "Test" 
end
```

**bookfinal.html.erb**

```
<div>
   The checked value is  <%= @checked %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'categories/new'
  get 'sessions/new'
  post 'categories' => 'categories#create'
  get 'users/edit'
  get 'users/new'
  get 'users/index'
  get 'users/mypage'
  post "users/bookfinal" => 'users#bookfinal' 
  resources :users
  resources :categories
```

**Console**

```
Started POST "/users/bookfinal" for 96.49.105.234 at 2016-02-19 21:18:21 +0000
Processing by UsersController#bookfinal as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zaPn5YuBFYr9VwPDSNMeA7tfm74sjM8HZneG+PCX9HEPEH/mb2qgA4xDacI9YDgcjDlFgKCQFFgWnUs5AZB0MA==", "category"=>{"title"=>"Digital Marketing", "Apple"=>"0", "iPhone"=>"0", "iPad"=>"1", "Mac"=>"0", "Android"=>"0", "Samsung"=>"0", "Microsoft"=>"0", "Windows"=>"0", "Google"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered users/bookfinal.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 115ms (Views: 113.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: write `routes.rb` please and server logs

Comment: @Ilya See routes and console posted.

Comment: seems like all right.. try to save your edits ans restart server

Comment: @Ilya Restarted, page is still blank

Comment: If you add debugging statements, are you only hitting the `#bookfinal` action?  If you manually set `@checked` in the action, it must be getting blanked on the way to `bookfinal.html.erb`.  Thus, the issue might not be in your logic, but somewhere in configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `bookfinal` method code to following:

```
@checked = params[:category].select{|k,v| !v.to_i.zero?}.keys.join
```

Comment: You are... awesome. THANK YOU. Using this method, is there away for me to reuse the checked values? Eg. once they appear on bookfinal.html.erb, can I include them in a new submission form on this page (which, inevitably will get emailed to the admin)?

Answer (score 1):

For your current params you can do something like this:

```
@checked = params[:category].except(:title).select { |brand, value| value == '1' }.keys.to_sentence
```

This will take params from `[:category]`, leave only selected and then make a sentence from brand names.
To handle case when nothing is selected, you can use this:

```
@checked = 'None' if @checked.blank?
```

There are cleaner solutions using form objects, etc. But this should work too

Comment: I replaced what was in def bookfinal with your above code, and still, nothing prints on my bookfinal.html.erb page.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *print the value*?

If you are getting either `0` or `1` from `params[:category][:ipad]` from instance, then everything's working as expected, [checkboxes rendered from the form helper return either 0 or 1 if they are unchecked or checked respectively](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box).

You *can't* get the checkbox label text that way. What the request is sending is the value of the html `input` element, and rails actually bounds it to a hidden field (that holds either 0 or 1) for reasons explained in the above link I posted.

So basically you have two options:

1. Create hidden fields to hold the text that you can actually send on the request and use as placeholders for such text on your next page or...
2. Simply check the actual value on your next page request and set variables that you then use to check whether or not print out certain labels

I'd go for option number 2, so you'll do something like this:

In your controller:

```
def bookfinal 
  if params[:category][:ipad] 
    @ipad_checked = true
  end  
end
```

*(you could also simply store the values on [flash storage](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html))*

And then in your `bookfinal.html.erb` view:

```
<div>
 <% if @ipad_checked %>
 <span>iPad is checked</span>
 <% end %> 
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this - still no result printed on bookfinal.html.erb :/

Comment: @Brittany What happens if you print out the value of the variable "@ipad_checked" on the view, what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

Here, from the params hash we an see that, the checked value of the ipad is '1' and the key is iPad and not ipad, please change the controller to this.

```js
def bookfinal 
  if params['category']['iPad'].present? 
    @checked = 'Ipad is checked'
  end 

  if params['category']['Apple'].present? 
    @checked = 'Apple is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['Samsung'].present? 
    @checked = 'Samsung is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['Microsoft'].present? 
    @checked = 'Microsoft is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['Android'].present? 
    @checked = 'Android is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['Mac'].present? 
    @checked = 'Mac is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['iPhone'].present? 
    @checked = 'iPhone is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['Windows'].present? 
    @checked = 'Windows is checked'
  end 
  if params['category']['Google'].present? 
    @checked = 'Google is checked'
  end 
  @checked = "Test" 
end
```

Your bookfinal.html.erb is,

```html
<div>
   <%= @checked %> 
</div>
```

Thats it. Done :-)

Here is your params hash and @category object,

```js
 params =  {"category"=>{"title"=>"Digital Marketing", "Apple"=>"0", "iPhone"=>"0", "iPad"=>"1", "Mac"=>"0", "Android"=>"0", "Samsung"=>"0", "Microsoft"=>"0", "Windows"=>"0", "Google"=>"0"}}

 if params['category']['iPad'].present?
   @category = "Ipad checked"
   end
 => "Ipad checked" 

 @category
 => "Ipad checked"
```

Comment: All I get when I implement the above on bookfinal.html.erb is: Test /* you will get message what is checked *?

Comment: remove those commented lines '/* you will get message what is checked *?' is not to be written. Those are comments, I have writtten them for your understanding.Any way I am removing them.